# Access C# static class from a C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll, extern, legacy-code

I've been tasked with writing a new interface to a legacy C++ DLL I don't have the source code for, which - for reasons beyond me - accesses a global class in the legacy application directly.

From the application, it's something like:

```
extern Interface *App;

...

Interface App*;   //  A pointer to our interface class.
```

Then, from the legacy DLL:

```
if( App->GetStatus() ) return false;
```

The Interface class that App refers to is quite trivial to rewrite in C#, but how can I make it the equivalent of `extern` so that the legacy C++ DLL can access it?

Thanks!

Comment: You are not going to get very far with this as long as your write `Interface App*`, understanding pointers is pretty critical to get somewhere.  Calling C# code from C++ requires getting the CLR loaded first.  There are many ways to do that the wrong way, that starts by using the "easy" ways.  Using the #import directive in C++ is a right way.  Educate yourself, ask your supervisor for the resources you need.

Comment: Bear in mind that the poster has said he doesn't have access to the C++ source code, so loading the CLR might be a problem...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Robert Giesecke's "[UnmanagedExports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports)" nuget package to achieve this functionality like so:

```
class Test
{
    [DllExport("add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static int TestExport(int left, int right)
    {
       return left + right;
    } 
}
```

**However**:

a) I believe this only works for methods, not classes and

b) the reason there isn't a native way to export a DLL in C# is because that the calling application must have the .NET framework loaded in order to access that entry point. This also applies to the UnmanagedExports nuget package that I linked to above.

You can hack your way around this by getting your C++ app to load mono before calling the C# app, but it doesn't sound like this is possible in your case.

*(Also, UnmanagedExports will only work if you explicitly set a build target in your project's properties - eg. x86)*

Comment: The .net framework is loaded as soon as one of your exported methods is called. Your c++ app can even be using a different version of the framework.

Comment: This only happens if your app is written in C++/CLI. If your C++ code is unmanaged it will not load the .net framework

Comment: I compiled a native c++ program from the command line `cl /EHsc MyConsoleApp.cpp /Fe: MyConsoleApp.exe`
In the cpp file I have `typedef void  (__stdcall * OPENDEVICES)();`
`OPENDEVICES OpenDevices;`
`HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("MyCSharpLib.dll");`
`OpenDevices = OPENDEVICES(GetProcAddress(HMODULE(hGetProcIDDLL), "OpenDevices") );`
This works. MyCSharplib.dll is created with .Net 4.0. I have a customer that uses Visual Studio 2005 and has no problem using this in there application.